# fluent-json-schema - how to make POST body required in openapi schema

Tags: fastify

Using fastify and fluent-json-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to make a POST route body required in the openapi schema output

```
const postSomethingSchema = S.object()
  .prop("fieldA", S.string())

export const postSchema = {
  operationId: "createSomething",
  body: postSomethingSchema,
  response: { 200: somethingSchema },
};
```

Today, this generates the following, (without the required key I'm looking for of course)

```
"post": {
  "operationId": "createSomething",
    "requestBody": {
      "required": true, // I can't figure out how to get this!
      "content": {...}
```

Comment: `const postSomethingSchema = S.object().prop("fieldA", S.string().required())`